# How to call the bar chat function in click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart

Here i am using bhar chat onloading it is working , my question is onclick the button also i want to call the same function , from this code where they are calling the function i am not able to get, if any one know means update my snippet.which purpose i am asking means clicking button that time i will pass the AJAX and again i will display the results

```js
$(function () { 
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#67BCE6'],
    chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
            color: '#fff'
        }
    }
});  
  $('#barchat').highcharts({
   
   
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: '#36394B'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Trip Details',
            style: {  
              color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickWidth: 0,
            labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#fff',
                 }
              },
            categories: ['Project', 'Escort', 'Adhoc']
        },
        yAxis: {
           gridLineWidth: .5,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
        gridLineColor: 'black',
           title: {
                text: '',
                style: {
                  color: '#fff'
                 }
            },
            labels: {
              formatter: function() {
                        return '$'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
                    },
              style: {
                  color: '#fff',
                 }
              }
            },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
           //valuePrefix: '$'
        },
        plotOptions: {
        column: {
         borderRadius: 2,
             pointPadding: 0,
         groupPadding: 0.1
            } 
      },
        series: [{
            name: 'No of trip used',
            data: [1000, 2000, 2300]
        }]
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Barchat -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="barchat" style="width:100%; height:320px;"></div>

<button id="clickMeBtn">CLick Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you're trying to reload the chart when the button is clicked. If so, please try this code:

```js
$(function () { 
    displayChart(['Project', 'Escort', 'Adhoc'],[1000, 2000, 2300]);
});

$('button#clickMeBtn').on('click',function(){
    displayChart(['Project', 'Escort', 'Adhoc'],[3000, 2000, 2300]);
});

function displayChart(aCategories,aData){
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#67BCE6'],
        chart: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                color: '#fff'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#barchat').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: '#36394B'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Trip Details',
            style: {  
              color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            categories: aCategories
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: .5,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
            gridLineColor: 'black',
            title: {
                text: '',
                style: {
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                            return '$'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#fff',
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            //valuePrefix: '$'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderRadius: 2,
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0.1
           } 
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'No of trip used',
            data: aData
        }]
    });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Barchat -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="barchat" style="width:100%; height:320px;"></div>

<button id="clickMeBtn">CLick Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate function for chat and pass new value  in button click like below snippet in AJAX call.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [1000, 2000, 2300];
  chart(data);
  $("#clickMeBtn").on("click", function() {
  //call AJAX and set new data and call chart function again.
    data = [2000, 1000, 2500] // New data
    chart(data);
  });

});

function chart(data) {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#67BCE6'],
    chart: {
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        color: '#fff'
      }
    }
  });
  $('#barchat').highcharts({


    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: '#36394B'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Trip Details',
      style: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      tickWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#fff',
        }
      },
      categories: ['Project', 'Escort', 'Adhoc']
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: .5,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
      gridLineColor: 'black',
      title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
          color: '#fff'
        }
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
        },
        style: {
          color: '#fff',
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      //valuePrefix: '$'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        borderRadius: 2,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.1
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'No of trip used',
      data: data
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Barchat -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="barchat" style="width:100%; height:320px;"></div>

<button id="clickMeBtn">CLick Me</button>
```